# What's the difference between json data being encoded or not

Tags: json, laravel

What's the purpose (not what it becomes) of doing `json_encode` on this before I am putting into the database

```
rating: {cleanliness: 3, publicFacility: 1, roomFacility: 2, security: 2}
```

to become this

```
rating: "{"cleanliness":3,"publicFacility":1,"roomFacility":2,"security":2}"
```

I see no point of doing this cause I need to `json_decode` it again before serving it back... can anybody clear me out?

Answer (score 0):

Do not store json encoded data in the database. You mitigate the whole point of a relational database this way and make searching for values an expensive task. I see in your sample the attributes cleanliness, publicFacility, roomFacility and security. Those should be columns in your database so you can search for something like "all entries with a cleanliness higher than 3".
It works with the JSON column type but it is more expensive than using normal columns.

**Edit**: Check the use-case for your database entry. If you are sure you never need to search in or order by the encoded attributes you can store data encoded as json string. However, if your database supports the JSON column type, you should use that one because it allows searching in the stored JSON (but is more expensive than searching in normal columns). **</Edit>**

Second point: The second code snipped (with the quotation marks) looks like invalid syntax for json.

Comment: the database column happens out to be `$table->json('rating')` so I want to keep it that way

the data was able to be stored in the database with some escaped column
`"{\"cleanliness\":3,\"publicFacility\":1,\"roomFacility\":2,\"security\":2}"`

Comment: If you already have the data that way, it's something else. But if you are going to store new data, you definitely should not use JSON in the database.

Comment: well using json format in the column has some utility though, i can add other things beside `cleanliness, publicFacility, roomFacility and security` without altering the database column

Comment: Say that he should not store data in json format inside a relational database without know the use case is not correct. Sometimes we just don't need use relational database features, we just need to store that information.

Comment: @EliasSoares true, I updated my answer to reflect that.